# If $H$ has finite index there are finitely many distinct subgroups of form $aHa^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> If $H$ has finite index there are finitely many distinct subgroups of form $aHa^{-1}$.

I tried the following:

Let the distinct left cosets of $H$ in $G$ be $a_1H ,a_2H, \dots, a_nH$. Then the distinct right cosets are $Ha_1^{-1}, Ha_2^{-1}, \dots, Ha_n^{-1}$.
Consider any subgroup $aHa^{-1}$. Now $aH=a_iH$ for some $i=1,2,\dots, n$. Then $Ha^{-1}=Ha_i^{-1}$. So $aHa^{-1}=a_iHa_i^{-1}$, proving these subgroups are finite in number.

In my proof I have used the following argument:
$$\begin{align}aH=bH &\iff a^{-1}b\in H \\
&\iff a^{-1}(b^{-1})^{-1}\in H\\
&\iff Ha^{-1}=Hb^{-1}
\end{align}$$

Is my proof okay?

**P.S.** I understand that all of the subgroups $a_iHa_i^{-1}$ need not be unique. For instance, the subgroup $3\Bbb Z$ has 3 distinct left/right cosets in $\Bbb Z$.
 However the only subgroup of the form $a+3\Bbb Z -a$ is $3\Bbb Z$.

Comment: It looks fine to me. You did not justify some of the implications but they're correct.

Comment: @Yanko Thank you. I have added another line.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your proof is correct, especially with the postscript note.